How does Firebase App Check manage the key pair, attestation and tokens?
According to Establishing your app’s integrity from Apple, the app needs to generate a key pair and Store the keyId in persistent storage.
My questions:
(1) When does the app client create the key pair and how often is the key pair generated on the device in a single app instance? Does it create every time AppCheckProvider is created? (I'll be using App Check only in specific condition of the app and setup only when needed)
(2) When is the App attestation being performed?
(3) If I setup consumeAppCheckToken = true for Firebase function call, does firebase perform ONLY Assertion on the server for every single firebase function call?
(4) If consumeAppCheckToken = false, does firebase manage the token automatically with no cost incurred to App Check?
Thank You!
